# Altair themes don't change default mark color

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, altair

When you use an Altair theme that has a different color scheme than the default one, the color scheme is only used when the color channel is encoded. When it's not encoded, the chart is in the default Altair color (blue), instead of the first color in the theme's color scheme.

Below is some code that demonstrates the problem.

```
import altair as alt
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('mpg')
alt.themes.enable('fivethirtyeight')

# properly uses the fivethirtyeight color scheme
chart1 = alt.Chart(df).mark_circle().encode(
    x='displacement'
    , y='mpg'
    , color='origin:N'
)
chart1.display()

# doesn't use the first color in fivethirtyeight, instead uses altair blue
chart2 = alt.Chart(df).mark_circle().encode(
    x='displacement'
    , y='mpg'
)
chart2.display()
```

Comment: This would need to be filed as an issue directly with vega-themes https://github.com/vega/vega-themes/tree/master or maybe vega-lite.